# Attach leftmenu to main content area

Tags: css

I know there is a link for this already, But it doesn't work for me.

Basically i want the bar on  the left to be attached to the middle area.

Demo: http://pvrpg.net/gerg/index.php#

My layout: http://www . pvrpg . net/gerg/layout

My HTML: http://www.pvrpg.net/gerg/index

Thanks if you can help.

I tagged this as CSS and CSS3, I don't know which it falls in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your sidebar and your middle area in a div (or any other element).
Then you need to set the width of this element to the width of the sidebar and the middle area combined (plus any whitespace between them). Then center the new element you added. You may also need to float the middle area right.